# Centering a CALayer Horizontally Inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerlayer

As the title says, I've gotten my video player to work, but it shows the video on the right side of the cell instead of centered. Not sure why, I've tried a lot of things on the internet, and I know my code is probably not amazing, but I just want to center it horizontally and it refuses to work with me. If I turn off `playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` it just outright disappears

`img_thumb` is an image that takes up the entirety of the space that will be a video thumbnail before it loads but right now is just a black background for the video, either way the full contentView has an additional element at the bottom so it's easier to use the `img_thumb` constraints

```
    playerView.frame = videoCell.img_thumb.frame
//                            playerView.layer.bounds = videoCell.img_thumb.bounds
//                            playerView.layer.frame = videoCell.img_thumb.frame
    playerView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: videoCell.img_thumb.bounds.midX, y: videoCell.img_thumb.bounds.midY)
    videoCell.contentView.addSubview(playerView)
    playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    playerView.bounds = videoCell.img_thumb.bounds
    playerView.center = videoCell.img_thumb.center
    playerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoCell.img_thumb.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    playerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoCell.img_thumb.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    playerView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: videoCell.img_thumb.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    playerView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: videoCell.img_thumb.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

My layout in Storyboard
[image: Layout in Storyboard]

The reason I use the UIImageView's constraints
[image: Reason I use UIImageView's constraints (orange bar)]

The constraints for ContentView of HomeVideoCell
[image: constraints for ContentView]

The actual created PlayerView
[image: created PlayerView view]

And finally what it actually looks like (with AutoLayout on)
[image: What it looks like with autolayout]

and finally PlayerView

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit

class PlayerView: UIView {
    private var url: URL?
    private var urlAsset: AVURLAsset?
    private var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    var loaded: Bool = false
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?
    
    private var assetPlayer:AVPlayer? {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let layer = self.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
                    layer.player = self.assetPlayer
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        initialSetup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        initialSetup()
    }
    
    private func initialSetup() {
        if let layer = self.layer as? AVPlayerLayer {
            // Do any configuration
            layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        }
    }
    
    func prepareToPlay(withUrl url:URL, shouldPlayImmediately: Bool = false) {
        guard !(self.url == url && assetPlayer != nil && assetPlayer?.error == nil) else {
            if shouldPlayImmediately {
                play()
            }
            return
        }
        
        cleanUp()
        
        self.url = url
        
        let options = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : true]
        let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: options)
        self.urlAsset = urlAsset
        
        let keys = ["tracks"]
        urlAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: keys, completionHandler: { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.startLoading(urlAsset, shouldPlayImmediately)
        })
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    }
    
    private func startLoading(_ asset: AVURLAsset, _ shouldPlayImmediately: Bool = false) {
        var error:NSError?
        let status: AVKeyValueStatus = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "tracks", error: &error)
        if status == AVKeyValueStatus.loaded {
            let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            self.playerItem = item
            
            let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
            self.assetPlayer = player
            self.loaded = true
            
            if shouldPlayImmediately {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    player.play()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func toggle() {
        if self.assetPlayer?.isPlaying == false {
            play()
        } else {
            pause()
        }
    }
    
    func play() {
        guard self.assetPlayer?.isPlaying == false else { return }
//        if self.loaded && self.activityIndicator != nil {
//            self.activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()
//        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.assetPlayer?.play()
        }
    }
    
    func pause() {
        guard self.assetPlayer?.isPlaying == true else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.assetPlayer?.pause()
        }
    }
    
    func cleanUp() {
        pause()
        urlAsset?.cancelLoading()
        urlAsset = nil
        assetPlayer = nil
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        cleanUp()
    }
    
    @objc private func playerItemDidReachEnd(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard notification.object as? AVPlayerItem == self.playerItem else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let videoPlayer = self.assetPlayer else { return }
            videoPlayer.seek(to: .zero)
            videoPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is not enough to give the right answer right away! we also need to see how you videoCell constraints are. and also please upload a screenshot so we know where all elements located. I can guess, but to tell you the true answer without just guessing, need to see you current view. but my first glimpse says that you are using Frames and Autolayout at the same time which may cause the problem.

Comment: Right, but if I disable Autolayout am I disabling it for the entire cell or just for the playerView? I'll post more code

Comment: @willow updated code with views, my PlayerView module, and constraints of ContentView as well as what it ends up with (if I disable autolayout it says I need to define more constraints but the width and height *are* defined?)

Comment: you used storyboard layout and in code both? some of them on storyboards are being layout some of them through codes?

Comment: @willow I didn't get a choice to be quite frank. I took over this project from some third world developers who used 8 year out of date packages and what not. I'm going to rewrite it once we present it, but yeah I have had to make do with what I was given for now due to a time constraint (haha constraint) -- I did update the packages though

Comment: it's really hard to figure out what your problem is, but I suggest to clean all your constraint from you storyboard, and setup in your code again. When you setup your layout with constraints, you should not use  Frame, Center, bounds, etc for that UI anymore. that is why Auto-layout has been created to stop using old-fashion way. I can see in you codes that is too messy and just make you more confused if you haven't written the code. but I try to guess and answer you now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252485/discussion-between-willow-and-zach-handley).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I as mentioned in comments it's really hard to figure out your problem. But try to replace the given code with this.Delete the block of code you shown me up, then replace it.

```
    videoCell.contentView.addSubview(playerView)
    playerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    playerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoCell.img_thumb.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    playerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: videoCell.img_thumb.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    playerView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: videoCell.img_thumb.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    playerView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: videoCell.img_thumb.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Turns out the issue was the `lessThanOrEqualTo`, I've accepted your answer as my code was still far more gross, and I appreciate your time, thank you!

Comment: Happy your code works. If you clean all your constrains from your storyboard and do it in your code, that will be more manageable.

Comment: Yeah I need to recode it in Swift UI tbh, it's so much better to work with then this half storyboard half code crap